# Error in carousel_slider when restart or reload

Tags: flutter, dart, carousel-slider

I'm using carousel_slider to change between my screen pages as a carousel, but when I click a button to change to another screen I use the method `animateToPage` from a `CarouselController` to change to the new screen -> `controller.animateToPage(pageIndex)`

```
  void handleButtonClick() {
    if (pageIndex != 1 && pageIndex != 2) {
      goToLogin!.call();
    } else {
      controller.animateToPage(pageIndex);
    }
  }
```

Every time I run the app it works perfectly, but if a try a hot restart or a hot reload I get the following error when clicking the button

> E/flutter ( 5497): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
> E/flutter ( 5497): #0      CarouselControllerImpl.animateToPage (package:carousel_slider/carousel_controller.dart:106:41)
> E/flutter ( 5497): #1      PresentationButton.handleButtonClick....

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

check whether pageIndex is null or not.

If it's null, try to initialize with a non null value like `int pageIndex = 0`

Comment: I used pageIndex = 0 and even though the error persisted. The only way I found to stop it was by changing the Stateless class to a Stateful class

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue: my carousel slider was working perfect, but after I updated the state, the controller functions were not longer working.

As @GustavoF mentioned, I solved the problem by declaring the `CarouselController` **in the State** of an **StatefulWidget**, then the build method will use this same controller as the parameter for the `CarouselSlider`